# Tuning and optimizing a MATLAB/Simulink Model

Tags: matlab, optimization, simulink

I would like to optimize output signals, by tuning some of the input parameters with ease (preferably in real-time) by looping the simulation of the model again and again at a speed where the speed of simulation can be controlled.

Answer (score 1):

You have various options as far as I can see.

The first one is to have the parameters of interest defined as workspace variables, and then write a MATLAB script looping over those variables, with the use of the [`sim`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/sim.html) command to run the Simulink model programmatically. You can control the "speed" of the simulations with things such as step size used by the solver. If you want to combine this with optimizing parameters, you can put the call to `sim` in a cost function, and then pass this to the optimization routine.

The second option is to use an add-on product called [Simulink Design Optimization](http://uk.mathworks.com/products/sl-design-optimization/), which provides a nice interface and uses optimization routines under the hood to loop over the parameters. This requires the Optimization Toolbox.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to invest nothing in the creation of your user interface, you might want to use cell evaluation. Check out [this link](http://in.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/run-sections-of-programs.html).

> Increment Values in Code Sections
>
> You can increment numbers within a section, rerunning that section
>   after every change. This helps you fine-tune and experiment with your
>   code.
>
> To increment or decrement a number in a section:
>
> Highlight or place your cursor next to the number. Right-click to open
>   the context menu. Select Increment Value and Run Section. A small
>   dialog box appears.
>
> Input appropriate values in the  /  text box or  /  text box. Click
>   the  ,  ,  , or   button to add to, subtract from, multiply, or divide
>   the selected number in your section. MATLAB runs the section after
>   every click.

Comment: What do you mean by investing? There are no ifs and buts, I would like to choose for myself what I would like to do. I know about GUIDE, and its time taking to setup but if it is possible to achieve my second goal using it, its worth a try.

Comment: @a.aniq, I mean investing your development time in writing a UI.

Comment: I think, you are talking about GUIDE, when talking about creating UI; that's why the comment. Even so, if you know of a way of achieving my final objective it would be great. Even at the cost of investing in creating UI.

Comment: I just visited the link, how can I incorporate your ideas into simulink model?

Comment: This is not a good suggestion for Simulink, only for MATLAB code.